# join between two tables with != condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

1. courses_available:

   ```
   Course | language
   -----------------
    A     | English
    A     | Spanish
   ```
2. courses_enrolled

   ```
   Name    |course | language
   --------------------------
   PersonA | A     | English
   PersonB | A     | Spanish
   PerconC | A     | French
   ```

I want to write a query to gives me records where a person is taking a course in an language that it is not offered in. In the above example, PersonC is taking course A in French but its only offered in English & Spanish.

```
select p.name, p.course, p.language from courses_available c, courses_enrolled p where p.course=c.course and p.language != c.language.
```

The above query is giving me course A as well. What kind of join will give me only C?

Comment: `select p.name, p.course, p.language from courses_enrolled p where (p.course, p.language) not in (select c.course, c.language from courses_available c)`

Comment: None. There is no course C

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps. Just use "<>" instead of !=

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM courses_available 
LEFT JOIN courses_enrolled ON courses_available.course = courses_enrolled.course
WHERE courses_available.language <> courses_enrolled.language
```

Comment: or same except 'WHERE courses_enrolled.course IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use '!=' you can add one more `on` condition

```
select ce.* from course c inner join courses_enrolled ce 
on 
c.Course = ce.Course 
and 
c.Language = ce.Language
```

you can see in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee95dd/3)

Answer (score 0):

use left join with condition `b.language is null`

```
select p.name, p.course, p.language 
from courses_enrolled a left join courses_available b
on a.course=b.course and a.language = b.language
where b.language is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists

```
Select  enrolled.*
From enrolled
Where.not exists (
Select 1
From courses
Where courses.id = enrolled.id
And courses.language = enrolled.language
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this by joining where language doesn't match, you want to join where it does match but only select rows where, with a left join, no courses_available is found:

```
select p.name, p.course, p.language
from courses_enrolled p
left join courses_available c on p.course=c.course and p.language = c.language
where c.course is null
```